# jquery select child elements

Tags: jquery

I'm very new to jQuery.

I wrote this code to select child TD elements.

```
$(this)
    .children("div.tablescroll_wrapper")
    .children("table.tablescroll_body")
    .children("tbody")
    .children("tr.first")
    .children()
```

It **works fine but looks bad**, Is there a better way to do this?

Sorry for my low level English and thank you

Comment: Could you please post the HTML you have so we can see how your DOM is structured. Also, what element does `$(this)` refer to in your example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure about your html structure, but what you are trying to achieve can be achieved with,

```
$(this).find("div.tablescroll_wrapper tr.first").children();
```

Comment: I know, but as I dont know the HTML structure I ended up with this one. Knowing his HTML structure will clarify everything. :)

Comment: well, cannot argue with this ;-) +1

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to navigate the entire tree. Just setting an id to the table or selecting tr directly will work:

```
   $(this).find('tr:first').children();
```

is good enough. Otherwise, select the table with the id of the table:

Comment: "you don't need" -- and what if they **do** need? ;-)

Comment: I didn't care actually. I just pointed that it's not correct to decide who needs what

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.tablescroll_wrapper > table.tablescroll_body > tr.first', this).children();
```

or

```
$('div.tablescroll_wrapper > table.tablescroll_body > tr.first > *', this);
```